# Offline web push notificaion

Tags: javascript, localstorage, push-notification, service-worker

Estou criando um to do list e, nele, quero poder criar notificações pré-programadas. A aplicação persiste todos os dados em Local Storage, ou seja, não tem o por quê usar um servidor de push notification

Então envio mensagens para o Service Worker para gerenciar as notificações:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
    .then(sw => {
        //Agenda uma futura notificação
        sw.active.postMessage({
            command: 'schedule',
            alert: { /* ... */ }
        });

        //Remove uma notificação agendada
        sw.active.postMessage({
            command: 'remove',
            alert: { /* ... */ }
        });
    })
    .catch(console.log);
```

E no Service Worker uso o `setTimeout` para agendar as notificações

```
class Alert {
    /* ... */
}

const timer = {};

self.addEventListener('message', event => {
    switch (event.data.command) {
        case 'schedule':
            schedule(new Alert(event.data.alert));
            break;

        case 'remove':
            remove(event.data.alert.key);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});

function remove(key) {
    if (timer[key]) {
        clearTimeout(timer[key]);

        delete timer[key];
    }
}

function schedule(alert) {
    if (!alert.canNotify()) {
        return;
    }

    remove(alert.key);

    timer[alert.key] = setTimeout(notify, alert.getTimeLeft(), alert.key, alert.title);
}

function notify(key, title) {
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        icon: '/assets/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png'
    });
}
```

Funciona, porém, após notificado o usuário, preciso avisar a aplicação para atualizar as informações no Local Storage, já que o Service Worker não tem acesso ao mesmo

Tentei enviar uma mesagem para os clientes na função `notify`:

```
self.clients.matchAll().then(
    clients => clients.forEach(
        client => {
            client.postMessage(key);
        }
    )
);
```

E na aplicação, atualizar os dados no evento `message`:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
    update(event.data);
});
```

Porém só funciona caso a aplicação estiver aberta, o que é um problema

Como posso atualizar esses dados?

Comment: `localStorage` só estará disponível se a aplicação estiver "aberta" ... talvez deve-se considerar o uso de `indexedDB` para operar em ambos os scripts

Comment: @LauroMoraes talvez seja a solução, mas não gostaria de ter que utilizá-lo porque, além de complicado, ele não persiste as informações para sempre

Comment: Eu não entendi a parte do "para sempre" mas concordo que é uma API "menos simples e menos intuitiva" do que `localStorage`

Comment: @LauroMoraes eventualmente o navegador apaga todo o storage sem nenhuma ação por parte do usuário ou da aplicação. Os dados são persistidos mas não há garantia que de hora pra outra tudo desapareça

Comment: Sim, mas isso afeta `localStorage` tbm. Sua aplicação já trabalha com um trabalhador e notificação podes querer olhar para o modo persistente: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageManager/persist ... mas ainda assim o usuário ou um plugin poderia limpar o cache, para pesistir de fato (e resiliente) somente no backend